# MeadCo ScriptX printing in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing

I am trying to use MeadCo ScriptX for client side printing in any version of IE 7 and later (only IE is needed). Some of the users around 1000 users have Windows XP, 7 and 8. Some have 64 bit and some 32 bit. I have no control over what version of OS and IE versions they have.

Currently we just use JavaScript for printing:`window.print()`.

But users have been complaining that sometimes the page does not fit 1:1 when printing landscape. To address 1:1 landscape I tried some CSS using this link. It helped to some extent but it in some cases it doesn't fit 1:1. http://www.cnblogs.com/blodfox777/archive/2008/09/16/1291888.html.

Since it is using the browsers print, I had no luck hiding header and footers using JavaScript except setting some IE settings.

Lastly since it uses `window.print`, I don't have control over print settings or font.

To overcome all these issues the above link suggests using MeadCo ScriptX. Currently I am just considering a free version.

What are some things I need to consider before using MeadCo ScriptX? Will it help me with all the above issues? What issues would I have during deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MeadCo ScriptX may help with ensuring the page fits 1:1 but that will only be if reducing the size of the print margins increases the printable area. You can set the margins using MeadCo ScriptX.

Yes you can control the heading and footer (including setting them to an empty string).

Font control on the printed content is entirely determined by the css and doesn't require MeadCo ScriptX. With ScriptX you can also control the font used for the header and footer.

A useful way to think about ScriptX is that it automates IE. If you can get the print out to reliably print 1:1 using IE print settings then you can reproduce all of that using (say) javascript - any changes you make using script are reverted when the users leaves the page so their default settings are not disturbed.

Deployment can be done using your enterprise distribution system with the .msi installer or you can use a cab file specified with the codebase attribute. Either method requires admin privileges for the installation. You do not need a different version of ScriptX for each version of IE, the latest version of MeadCo ScriptX work with IE 5.5 through IE 11 on each OS the browser version is available on. ScriptX doesn't work with Edge because Edge does not allow binary extensions.

Scripting must be enabled, as must the ability to run ActiveX controls. If you can avoid IE 8, do so. It works but there are some annoying issues that are not present with IE 7 or 9 or later.

As you are only using the free version of ScriptX with is x86 only, always use the 32bit edition of IE even on x64 systems.

Comment: This is how I have the page margins now ..if (MeadCo.ScriptX.Init()
            
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.leftMargin = 0.70
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.topMargin = 0.0
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.rightMargin = 0.0
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.bottomMargin = 0.0
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.header = "";
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.footer = "";
                MeadCo.ScriptX.Printing.orientation = "landscape";
                MeadCo.ScriptX.PreviewPage(false);
            }

Comment: Other than setting left margin to 0.7 instead of 0 that is all correct code and if it doesn't print 1:1 then your layout is too large for the printable area available (taking into account the printers own minimum margin).

Comment: Just to clarify, there are two issues with specifying margins. The first is units - I presume you mean 0.7 inches but is that the measurement system on all your systems?

Comment: If some systems are using mm you are not going to get the result you hoped for.
The second is that IE measures print margin from the paper edge but printers have their own minimum margin. Is 0.7 inches less than your printer minimum margin? You can see the minimum margin by using Page setup ... from the gear print menu and then set 0 for each margin. OK the dialog and then open again. You will see the min values
 for margin.

Comment: OK thank you. Can I ask another question: Is there a way I could conditionally set the topmargin. I don't want to hardcode it to 0.0. I want it to adjust the top margin in a such way that it fits 1:1 landscape

Comment: Also, does everyone who uses Meadco need admin rights.

Comment: Admin rights are required for installation only, not for running the code. 

On the margins, I don't understand what conditions you could use. It may be that some of the licensed features of ScriptX may help, but I think discussion of these here are outside the scope of Stackoverflow and this question. Please see the ScriptX docs and contact MeadCo or use the forums there.